# Spring event routing in case of generic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

I want to build event processing based on event generic type.

Event class:

```
public class PushNotificationStoreEvent<T extends Push> extends ApplicationEvent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3791059956099310853L;

    public T push;

    public PushNotificationStoreEvent(Object source, T push) {
        super(source);
        this.push = push;
    }
}
```

*Here `Push` is marker interface for classes: `PushNotificationNew` and `PushNotificationFail`.*

Listeners:

```
@Async
@EventListener
public void storeNewPush(PushNotificationStoreEvent<PushNotificationNew> event) {
    pushNewRepoService.save(event.push);
}
@Async
@EventListener
public void storeFailPush(PushNotificationStoreEvent<PushNotificationFail> event) {
    pushFailRepoService.save(event.push);
}
```

Problem: there is no distinction between `PushNotificationStoreEvent<PushNotificationNew>` and `PushNotificationStoreEvent<PushNotificationFail>`  for listeners.

It means, that all events `PushNotificationStoreEvent` are processed by all listeners.

I can solve that by creating separate event class per case or use one listener and `instanceof` by `event.push` to choose right action. Maybe you know better solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I would like to avoid creating a cohort of classes like `PushNotificationStoreEventNew` and `PushNotificationStoreEventFail`, and use generic typed events like you describe here.

Comment: @MichaelFulton No, I've chosen one method and `instanceof` inside.